# PHP regex for password validation

Tags: php, regex

I not getting the desired effect from a script. I want the password to contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and special chars.

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9 >= 2
- special chars >= 2
- string length >= 8

So I want to force the user to use at least 2 digits and at least 2 special chars. Ok my script works but forces me to use the digits or chars back to back. I don't want that. e.g. password testABC55$$ is valid - but i don't want that.

Instead I want test$ABC5#8 to be valid. So basically the digits/special char can be the same or diff -> but must be split up in the string.

PHP CODE:

```
$uppercase = preg_match('#[A-Z]#', $password);
$lowercase = preg_match('#[a-z]#', $password);
$number    = preg_match('#[0-9]#', $password);
$special   = preg_match('#[\W]{2,}#', $password); 
$length    = strlen($password) >= 8;

if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$special || !$length) {
  $errorpw = 'Bad Password';
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem with that code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you can combine this into a single regex.

Comment: The code works however not to the desired effect. Note my pw example above

Comment: I'm just forcing the user to make a more secure password. How am I "stopping" you Dagon? I don't see issue. You may have a weak "preferred password" in my opinion.

Comment: The simple answer is, don't use a regex. A regex is not designed to do this, and the amount of effort you need to put into twisting its arm to your will could be used to easily create a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using *"readable"* format (it can be optimized to be shorter), as you are regex newbie >>

```
^(?=.{8})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d])[-+%#a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

Add your special character set to last `[...]` in the above regex (I put there for now just *-+%#*).

---

***Explanation:***

```
^                              - beginning of line/string
(?=.{8})                       - positive lookahead to ensure we have at least 8 chars
(?=.*[A-Z])                    - ...to ensure we have at least one uppercase char
(?=.*[a-z])                    - ...to ensure we have at least one lowercase char
(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d                - ...to ensure we have at least three digits
(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d]) 
                               - ...to ensure we have at least three special chars
                                    (characters other than letters and numbers)
[-+%#a-zA-Z\d]+                - combination of allowed characters
$                              - end of line/string
```

Comment: Omega, I appreciate your response however I find your form of RegEx confusing as I am a novice. Can you elaborate that code in pieces please?

Comment: Nice answer... was that `(?=` a look before or a look after? By the way you should explain that.

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - I have updated my answer with such information

Comment: @rekire - `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead (see updated answer)

Comment: How does (?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d]) ensure special chars? The RegEx reference shows \W as special chars. Thanks for the explanation though. Also for chars allowed - say I want @#$ would that look like this: [/@/#/$a-zA-Z\d]+

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d].*[^a-zA-Z\d])` is a positive lookahead = condition that has to be fulfilled to find a match. This condition is: some or no chars `.*`, followed by special char `[^a-zA-Z\d]`, followed by some or no chars, followed by special char. Special character is defined as `[^a-zA-Z\d]`, which is any character other than letter or digit. At the end of regex you have set or chars that are allowed `[-+%#a-zA-Z\d]` with `+` behind, which means one or more. There is no separator for chars in `[...]` set. List `-` as first and don't list `^` as first one.

Comment: I see what you're doing [^a-zA-Z\d] == to \W

Comment: Ok I will use that thank you. What is the benefit and/or reason of using [^a-zA-Z\d] instead of \W ?

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - that is not true: `[^a-zA-Z\d]` is not same as `\W`, becase underscore `_` is not part of `\W` set.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?=(.*\d){3,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(.*[!@#$%^&]){3,}).{8,})
```

test$ABC5#8 is not valid because you ask more than 2 digits and spec symbols

```
A-Z
a-z
0-9 > 2
special chars > 2
string length >= 8
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion. Note the code. It is invalid because the characters not adjacent. It validates if for example I use: test$$ABC44  I will corrected the example. sorry

Comment: switch {3,} to {2,} in digit and spec symbols and it will be pass

Answer (score 0):

For matching length of string including special characters:

$result = preg_match('/^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.\d)(?=.[^A-Za-z\d])[\s\S]{6,16}$/', $string);

Answer explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359397/5466401

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Look ahead is nice for this...

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*\W.*\W)[a-zA-Z0-9\S]{4,}$/
```

**EXPLAINED in pieces below**

Look ahead/require for a lower case:

```
(?=.*[a-z])
```

Look ahead/require an uppercase:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])
```

Look ahead/require 2 digits:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

Look ahead/require any 2 non-word chars (same as [^a-zA_Z0-9_]):

```
(?=.*\W.*\W)
```

Entire password must contain a minimum of 4, a maximum is not defined, and only alpha numeric and special chars (non white-space):

```
[\S]{4,}
```