# Using preg_match to identify a strong password

Tags: php, regex, html

I had thought to use preg_match() to check if a password is correctly entered.  I want at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 1 lowercase letter, at least one number, and at least one special char.  Here's what I am using:

```
$pattern = "(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$";
```

This regex is working fine in HTML's "pattern" field.  But I need to ensure that it's also verified for older browsers.

My PHP code is this:

```
if (!(preg_match($pattern, $loginpassword))) {echo "Password must include one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character such as $ or %."; die;}
```

I thought it was working great except when I use the password 1@abcdeF it also fails to match.  The php code seems to work but no password ever matches, even when it SHOULD fit the pattern.  HTML5 will let it through so I suspect the regex statement is correct, but something about my setup in PHP is flawed.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Include error messages in your question. It's extremely obvious that this code sample would throw an error.

Comment: @Evert, I'm not getting any error messages.  It's just not matching.  The code is all working.  Sorry, I'll edit "fails" to be more specific so that's clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP regex needs regex delimiters also, so use:

```
$pattern = '/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/';
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same issue.  It still doesn't let !@abcdeF through and it should...  :-(

Comment: Hee, not saying the regex doesn't work...but something in the way that I'm implementing it seems to be wrong.  Is the syntax for using "preg_match" above correct?

Comment: Argh.  Just realized that my code was looking at the hash, not the password.  Homer Simpson...dooh.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following pattern:

*$strong_password = preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z\d])[\s\S]{6,16}$/', $string);*

```
^                 --> start of string

(?=.*[a-z])       --> at least one lowercase letter 

(?=.*[A-Z])       --> at least one uppercase letter 

(?=.*\d)          --> at least one number 

(?=.*[^A-Za-z\d]) --> at least one special character

[\s\S]{6,16}      --> total length between 6 and 16

$                 --> end of string
```

Comment: I would suggest to replace the 2 selectors "\s\S" with " \S" (literally the space character and any non-whitespace character), because your current solution allows a password on more than one line.